# Pattern for Decimal Format

Tags: java

I would like to translate `10000000.0` to `PREFIX10,000,000.00`

May I know what pattern I should pass into DecimalFormat?

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat(...);
numberFormat.format(10000000.0);
```

Comment: mohammad :o salam! i am happy to see you here :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
new DecimalFormat("PREFIX#,##0.00");
```

This will always show at least one integer digit (e.g. 0), and use comma as group separator.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern for the number would be: `"#,###.00"` which means:

1. use a grouping separator, based on locale
2. use a decimal separator, based on locale
3. always have 2 places after the decimal separator
4. have as many whole number digits as is necessary

The prefix can be an arbirary string.  If it is a currency symbol, there is a special notation for that.  For more info on the definition of patterns, see the [DecimalFormat JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)